# jQuery fullCalendar hourly event endTime

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I am using **jQuery fullCalendar** in my application.

Because I used `displayEventEnd: true` in my code, in the calendar it shows events as `startTime - endTime Title` e.g. `09:00 - 12:00 Meeting`.

But when an event is an hourly event, it only says `09:00 Meeting`, not `09:00 - 10:00 Meeting`.

I want to show endTime always. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [displayEventEnd](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/displayEventEnd/) documentation:

> If an event does not have an end date/time, it won't be displayed
>   anyway, regardless of this setting.

From OP:

> But when an event is an hourly event, it only says 09:00 Meeting, not
>   09:00 - 10:00 Meeting.

In that case, you're the only one who knows that it's a 1 hour range since `end:` is not provided.

I'm not sure if you're allowed to modify the library but when I take a look in `fullcalendar.js` or `fullcalendar.min.js` (check your reference in html) i see the following part that formats the text in event element.

```
getEventTimeText: function(range, formatStr) {

        formatStr = formatStr || this.eventTimeFormat;

        if (range.end && this.displayEventEnd) {
            return this.view.formatRange(range, formatStr);
        }
        else {
            return range.start.format(formatStr);
        }
    }
```

If you replace

```
return range.start.format(formatStr);
```

with

```
return range.start.format(formatStr) + ' - ' + range.start.clone().add(1,'hour').format(formatStr);
```

it will work accordingly.

**EDIT**

The following version looks better

```
if (range.end && this.displayEventEnd) {
    return this.view.formatRange(range, formatStr);
}
else if (this.displayEventEnd){
    return range.start.format(formatStr) + ' - ' + range.start.clone().add(1,'hour').format(formatStr);
    //or 
    //return this.view.formatRange({start: range.start,end: range.start.clone().add(1,'hour')}, formatStr ,' - ');
}
else{
    return range.start.format(formatStr);
}
```